# Does wrong CPU heat sensor reading possible?

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, cooling, temperature

I've got Dell Inspiron 15 5593  Intel® Core™ i5-1035G1 Processor (6MB Cache, 1.0GHz up to 3.9 GHz), when i run two node applications and CPU usage got higher then fan runs full steam.

Then i used CPU heat monitor took, it showed that for all 4 cores heat is 100C maximum and not less than 85C. But fan exhaust doesn't release that much heat at all.

As per last option i removed the back plate read heat manually using thermometer, and the readings are way off, If thermometer reading is 50C monitor tool show 100c.

Does it affect the CPU ?

Comment: CPU monitoring tools might be misreading the values if they have not been updated for that CPU. Are you having any real problem?

Comment: Try SpeedFan https://www.almico.com/sfdownload.php

Comment: "As per last option I removed the back plate read heat manually using a thermometer, and the readings are way off" - You were not measuring the samething, so I am not shocked, that the readings were not the same.  The sensors measure the CPU temperatures are absolutely accurate.  I can almost guarantee you that based on the temperatures you describe your CPU is being thermally throttled.

Comment: @Ramhound what can i do about it, i have reapplied the thermal compound which is having better thermal conductivity, now it reached the lesser temperature than previously had, and yet sometimes it reaching the 70-80C.

Comment: @Mokubai, for now no problem, but CPU temperature reaching 100C is not good as per my knowledge, so I'm looking for solution

Comment: 70-80 C is 20 degrees within the thermal limits of the processor, it’s a laptop, it’s going to run slightly hotter due to its design.

Comment: @Ramhound but what about when it reaches over 95C, is it normal too

Comment: Unless it’s shutting off, the processor will adjust its performance, to reduce the heat. If a specific work load is to much for your machine, then reduce the work load.